# Compare data from two tables and check the same data

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

Hello I have two tables in my database.

The first one is table disease which look like the above...

[image]

And the second is table patient which look like this ...

[image]

And I have an edit page where I want to give the user the ability to update his/her diseases. An example is the below..

[image]

What I want to do is to check the disease column from the table patient with the column name from the table disease and check that if a data from the table patient is the same with the data from the table disease then check from the checkboxes the same disease.

I tried to find a way to do it by I couldnt
Here is my code...

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT name FROM disease UNION SELECT disease FROM patient WHERE username='$username'";
$query_resource = mysql_query($sql);

  while( $name = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource) ):
?>
    <span><?php echo $name['name']; ?></span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>" /><br />


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The way I store the diseases in my database is this...

```
$disease = implode(",",$_POST["disease"]);
```

Because a user might have many diseases

Comment: It sounds you need make sure if the checked  value(s) inputed by user is in disease table.

Comment: "The way I store the diseases in my database is this..." STOP. See normalization. Construct a separate table which stores the patient_id and the disease_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer is not what you would be looking for however. if u building this application you should consider integrating relations between person and desies tables. besause it's MySql relational databases :)

If i got you right: NOT TESTED

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT disease FROM patient WHERE username='$username'";
$query_resource = mysql_query($sql);
$person = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource);

$persons_desisies = explode(',', $person['disease']);

$sql = "SELECT name FROM disease";
$query_resource = mysql_query($sql);
$disease = Array(); 
  while( $name = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource) ):
      ?>
      <span><?php echo $name['name']; ?></span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($name['name'], $persons_desisies)): ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?>/><br />

  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Idea - you are getting patiens desieses list and then checking with the full desies list. :)

Comment: but you understand this is wrong way to do it :) but good luck!

Comment: Yes I tried to use explode by myself but didnt do it right, and with your code i figure out what i was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

For further consideration:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS patients;

CREATE TABLE patients 
(patient_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO patients VALUES
(101,'Adam'),
(102,'Ben'),
(103,'Charlie'),
(104,'Dan');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS diseases;

CREATE TABLE diseases 
(disease_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,disease VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO diseases (disease) VALUES
('Allergy'),
('Cardiological'),
('Dermatological'),
('Gastrointestinal'),
('Gynaecological'),
('Ophthalmological'),
('Pathological'),
('Otorhinolaryngological'),
('Nephrological'),
('Neurological');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS patient_disease;

CREATE TABLE patient_disease
(patient_id INT NOT NULL
,disease_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(patient_id,disease_id)
);

INSERT INTO patient_disease VALUES 
(101,3),
(101,5),
(101,6),
(102,1),
(103,1),
(103,7),
(103,8);

SELECT p.*
     , d.*
     , CASE WHEN pd.disease_id IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END manifest 
  FROM patients p 
  JOIN diseases d 
  LEFT 
  JOIN patient_disease pd 
    ON pd.patient_id = p.patient_id 
   AND pd.disease_id = d.disease_id 
 ORDER BY p.patient_id
     , d.disease_id;
+------------+---------+------------+------------------------+----------+
| patient_id | name    | disease_id | disease                | manifest |
+------------+---------+------------+------------------------+----------+
|        101 | Adam    |          1 | Allergy                | no       |
|        101 | Adam    |          2 | Cardiological          | no       |
|        101 | Adam    |          3 | Dermatological         | yes      |
|        101 | Adam    |          4 | Gastrointestinal       | no       |
|        101 | Adam    |          5 | Gynaecological         | yes      |
|        101 | Adam    |          6 | Ophthalmological       | yes      |
|        101 | Adam    |          7 | Pathological           | no       |
|        101 | Adam    |          8 | Otorhinolaryngological | no       |
|        101 | Adam    |          9 | Nephrological          | no       |
|        101 | Adam    |         10 | Neurological           | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |          1 | Allergy                | yes      |
|        102 | Ben     |          2 | Cardiological          | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |          3 | Dermatological         | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |          4 | Gastrointestinal       | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |          5 | Gynaecological         | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |          6 | Ophthalmological       | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |          7 | Pathological           | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |          8 | Otorhinolaryngological | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |          9 | Nephrological          | no       |
|        102 | Ben     |         10 | Neurological           | no       |
|        103 | Charlie |          1 | Allergy                | yes      |
|        103 | Charlie |          2 | Cardiological          | no       |
|        103 | Charlie |          3 | Dermatological         | no       |
|        103 | Charlie |          4 | Gastrointestinal       | no       |
|        103 | Charlie |          5 | Gynaecological         | no       |
|        103 | Charlie |          6 | Ophthalmological       | no       |
|        103 | Charlie |          7 | Pathological           | yes      |
|        103 | Charlie |          8 | Otorhinolaryngological | yes      |
|        103 | Charlie |          9 | Nephrological          | no       |
|        103 | Charlie |         10 | Neurological           | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          1 | Allergy                | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          2 | Cardiological          | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          3 | Dermatological         | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          4 | Gastrointestinal       | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          5 | Gynaecological         | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          6 | Ophthalmological       | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          7 | Pathological           | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          8 | Otorhinolaryngological | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |          9 | Nephrological          | no       |
|        104 | Dan     |         10 | Neurological           | no       |
+------------+---------+------------+------------------------+----------+
```